# Crontab closing background process?

Tags: bash, cron, background-process

I am testing a bash script I hope to run as a cron job to scan a download log and perform labor-intensive conversions on image files. In order to run several conversions at once, the first script loops through the download log and sends the filename to the second script, which I set to run as a background process using &.

The script pair works well, but when the process is complete, I must press the enter key to return to a command prompt. This is a non-issue when I am running a test, but I am not sure if this behavior has ramifications when run as a cron job.

Will this be an issue? If so, is there a way to close the "terminal" running the first script from the crontab?

Here's a truncated form of my code:

Script 1 (to be launched by crontab):

```
for i in file1 file2 file3 etc
do
bash /path/to/convert.sh $i &
done
exit 0
```

Script 2 (convert.sh)

```
fileName=${1?no file given}
jpegName=$(echo $fileName | sed s/tif/jpg/g)
convert $fileName $jpegName
exit 0
```

Thanks for any help/assurances you can give!

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to return to the command prompt, you should get the prompt as soon as Script 1 finishes.

Comment: Does Script 2 produce output on the terminal? That output will be printed after the command prompt, and you need to press Return to get *another* prompt after it. But you don't have to do that, you can just type commands without getting another prompt.

Comment: When you run as a cron job there's no command prompt, so I don't see how this could be an issue.

Comment: you don't need script two. you can convert it to function and put it inside script1, another problem is you are running convert.sh in an uncontrolled way. You cannot foresee how many processes will be created and you can overload linux

Comment: Thanks, Barmar - I would assume that you are right, that when script 1 finishes, it should return me to the prompt. Alas, this is not what happens. It is intuitive to assume that since cron isn't running in a terminal that terminal behavior is irrelevant, but I am relatively new and it's nice to have that intuition validated.

Comment: Aha - I see, Barmar. The point is that the command prompt is there and active once script 1 finishes, it's just that it's in front of script 2's terminal output... Forgive my sluggishness on this point.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need script 2. you can convert it to function and put it inside script1.

Another problem is you are running convert.sh in an uncontrolled way. You cannot foresee how many processes will be created (background processes) and this may lead to severe performance overheads.

finally, if you cannot end process in normal way, you may choose to terminate it again using cron by issueing `pkill script1.sh`

Comment: Thanks, Simonare - I didn't fully characterize what I am trying to do or include enough code to show it. I'm trying to multi-thread the conversion process so it doesn't take forever. From my understanding, if I use only one script, each conversion will need to finish before the next one starts. The "real-life" version of Script 1 limits the number of processes launched so as to not overwhelm the server. Are you saying that if I turn the conversion command into a function, I can launch multiple threads from a single script?